# What targets are available for the swiftc -target and -target-cpu option?

Tags: swift, swift3

this question is about cross compilation.

What kind of different targets are available using the **-target** or **-target-cpu** option of the swift compiler? 
Where can I find an overview?

Is it only there to create iOS/watchOS apps or can I use it to create linux programs (regular x86-64 processor) on macOS?

I tried searching the github repository and found **'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'** as a target. However when I try to compile a simple "hello world" program (swiftc -target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu test.swift) I get this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to load standard library for target 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
```

**Edit:**
I agree with CristiFati. The last part of this question is rather about how to properly include/reference the [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/started.html) (?!?).

Comment: That is something that I would also like to know! strange why there's no answer at all

Comment: _Note_ regarding the error: when building a piece of code for a specific config (arch/platform) you need to have all the dependencies (e.g. libraries) for that config at build (and run) time. When I wrote some _C_ code for _OSX_, I was surprised to find out that the _.dylib_ that I was building, could have _i386_, _x86\_64_, _ppc_, _ppc64_ compiled code inside (and apparently could be used on any _OSX_ running on those archs).

Comment: Here is swift build support [target.py](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/utils/swift_build_support/swift_build_support/targets.py). You will see different target from [line 157 in Swift repository](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/utils/swift_build_support/swift_build_support/targets.py#L157)

Answer (score 17):

If you look at [Swift repository on Github](https://github.com/apple/swift) (Exact location: `swift/utils/swift_build_support/swift_build_support/targets.py`) You will see all host targets at [line 149-192](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1f94b62f47e0b9c4985c83a6e198c52204a5107b/utils/swift_build_support/swift_build_support/targets.py#L149-L192) in [target.py](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/utils/swift_build_support/swift_build_support/targets.py).

#### Supports:

```py
def host_target():
    """
    Return the host target for the build machine, if it is one of
    the recognized targets. Otherwise, throw a NotImplementedError.
    """
    system = platform.system()
    machine = platform.machine()

    if system == 'Linux':
        if machine == 'x86_64':
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.Linux.x86_64
        elif machine.startswith('armv7'):
            # linux-armv7* is canonicalized to 'linux-armv7'
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.Linux.armv7
        elif machine.startswith('armv6'):
            # linux-armv6* is canonicalized to 'linux-armv6'
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.Linux.armv6
        elif machine == 'aarch64':
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.Linux.aarch64
        elif machine == 'ppc64':
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.Linux.powerpc64
        elif machine == 'ppc64le':
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.Linux.powerpc64le
        elif machine == 's390x':
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.Linux.s390x

    elif system == 'Darwin':
        if machine == 'x86_64':
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.OSX.x86_64

    elif system == 'FreeBSD':
        if machine == 'amd64':
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.FreeBSD.x86_64

    elif system == 'CYGWIN_NT-10.0':
        if machine == 'x86_64':
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.Cygwin.x86_64

    elif system == 'Windows':
        if machine == "AMD64":
            return StdlibDeploymentTarget.Windows.x86_64

    raise NotImplementedError('System "%s" with architecture "%s" is not '
                              'supported' % (system, machine))
```

Comment: That's great information. Thanks. Can you add the actual (text) values that these things result in? Otherwise the answer feels incomplete.